# ¿Qué significa el símbolo ~ usado como selector en CSS?

Tags: css, selectores-css

Estaba buscando una forma de cambiar el texto que hay encima de un *input* en una pagina de *login* y encontre esta *syntax* que funciona y hace lo que debe, pero no entiendo muy bien como funciona, o lo que esta pasando ahí, intuyo que cuando se activa el focus, es decir, cuando se hace *click* encima del *input* pasa algo con el texto en *label*.

```
 input:focus ~ label
```

Comment: No se si sera lo mismo pero yo usaba esta, input:focus + label cuando haces focus en un input aplica la clase al elemento label que esta asociado a ese input por el for=" " por ejemplo cambiandolo de color, aca hay un ejemplo http://jsfiddle.net/4d9dm/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El selector `~` sirve para aplicar un estilo a un elemento que esté precedido por otro. En este caso aplica el estilo al `label` precedido por un `input` y a su vez, el `input` debe estar en `focus`.

```css
 input:focus ~ label{
   color:red;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>hola</label>
```

Answer (score 5):

El `~` es un combinador que se utiliza para [seleccionar hermanos generales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_generales). Separa dos selectores, y selecciona el segundo elemento sólo si está precedido por el primero y ambos comparten un padre común. Es decir, selecciona el segundo elemento si es un hermano del primero (están al mismo nivel y tienen el mismo padre) que aparece después en el código.

A diferencia de `+` (que es el [combinador de hermano adyacente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_adyacentes)), el segundo selector puede ser cualquier elemento que aparezca después y no directamente de forma seguida. Por lo tanto, `~` es más genérico: puede seleccionar más de un elemento y esos elementos no tienen por qué ser contiguos.

Aquí dejo unos ejemplos de uso:

```css
input:focus ~ label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Ejemplo 1:</h2>
  <input />
  <label>Este label se pondrá azul cuando el input gane foco.</label>
  <div>
    <label>Pero éste no, porque no es un hermano.</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Ejemplo 2:</h2>
  <input />
  <label>Este label se pondrá azul cuando el input gane foco.</label>
  <span>Esto es un span y no cambiará.</span>
  <label>Y esto es un label que también cambiará a azul a pesar de no estar seguido.</label>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Ejemplo 3:</h2>
  <p>
    ...entonces, ¡cuidado! Éste selector es genérico y podrías estar seleccionando más 
    de lo que esperas si no se organiza bien el código.
  </p>
  <input />
  <label>Este label se pondrá azul cuando el primer input gane foco.</label><br/>
  <input />
  <label>¡Este label se pondrá azul cuando cualquiera de los dos inputs gane foco!</label>
</section>
```